# Parsing multiple arguments into a bash script

Tags: bash, terminal, arguments

I've tried a few solutions posted here, but to no avail. I'm hoping it's something silly and obvious that I've missed, that you can spot easily, and I can facepalm myself.

I have a bash script containing multiple commands for data analysis. If I were to run this script on the command line, it would look something like this (simplified):

```
./script.sh /path/to/file1.gz /path/to/file2.gz output_name
```

My first two arguments are paths to files needed in the commands in the `script.sh` for data analysis. The `output_name`, is, as you'd expect, the name of the file that's output at the end.

This works fine, but I want to instead have a file containing the paths to multiple files, each on a new line, and loop over each line in the file and run the script sequentially. So the arguments file would look like:

```
/path/to/file1.gz /path/to/file2.gz output_name1
```

On each line.

And then feed each line into the script in a while loop (I figure this is best anyway).

I tried:

```
while read -r line; do; ./script.sh; done < arg_list.txt
```

Where arg_list.txt is the file containing my list of input arguments, I got "failed to open file `'."

Feel free to tell me I'm stupid and missing something!

Comment: If you're wondering why you get that error, it's likely because your loop doesn't actually pass any arguments to the script at all. If something inside tries to do e.g. `somecmd "$1"`, it'll just pass an empty string to the command, and that empty string isn't a valid filename (though for some reason it gives the error for a nonexisting file, not that for an invalid value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your own structure, read in three whitespace-separated values per line and use them as the arguments to the script

```
while read -r in1 in2 out
do
    ./script.sh "$in1" "$in2" "$out"
done < arg_list.txt
```

Comment: A variation: `while read -ra words; do ./script.sh "${words[@]}"; done < file`

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the contents of your input file is properly quoted (in the case where any of the arguments contain spaces, tabs, or newlines), then you may use `xargs` like so:

```bash
xargs -n 3 ./script.sh <arg_list.txt
```

This reads three arguments from the input at a time and calls your script with them.

A group of three arguments don't need to be listed on the same line in the input file, `xargs` will read three arguments and call your script with them, regardless of whether they are on the same line or spread across two or three lines.

Example (using a `printf` command in place of a script):

```bash
$ cat file
/path/to/file1.gz /path/to/file2.gz output_name1
/path/to/file1.gz /path/to/file2.gz output_name1
'/path/to/file 1.gz' /path/to/file2.gz output_name1
/path/to/file1.gz /path/to/file2.gz output_name1
/path/to/file1.gz
/path/to/file2.gz output_name1
/path/to/file1.gz /path/to/file2.gz output_name1
```

```bash
$ xargs -n 3 printf 'Arg1: "%s", Arg2: "%s", Arg3: "%s"\n' <file
Arg1: "/path/to/file1.gz", Arg2: "/path/to/file2.gz", Arg3: "output_name1"
Arg1: "/path/to/file1.gz", Arg2: "/path/to/file2.gz", Arg3: "output_name1"
Arg1: "/path/to/file 1.gz", Arg2: "/path/to/file2.gz", Arg3: "output_name1"
Arg1: "/path/to/file1.gz", Arg2: "/path/to/file2.gz", Arg3: "output_name1"
Arg1: "/path/to/file1.gz", Arg2: "/path/to/file2.gz", Arg3: "output_name1"
Arg1: "/path/to/file1.gz", Arg2: "/path/to/file2.gz", Arg3: "output_name1"
```

Comment: This was also really useful, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Actually, if your file contains the exact list of parameters, then the loop become extremely simple:

```
while read
do
   ./script.sh $REPLY
done
```

The `REPLY` variable is an automatic variable used if you do not supply a new name to the `read`. The `REPLY` also does not split the line into fields and therefore can be used as is.
Please note absence of quotes in this case. If the line read from the file contains spaces and quotes - they would transfer to the command exactly as they are in the file. So if you have a line in the file `a b "c d"` you would get a call to the script as `script.sh a b "c d"` - three parameters with a space in the last one.
So you have to ensure proper quoting inside the file.

If the parameters you read from file need to be updated somehow, then you can do a more elaborate `read`:

```
while read f1 f2 f3
do
   ./script.sh "$f2" "$f1" "$f3.txt"
done
```

Please note quoting in the file in this case too. For the same line `a b "c d"`, this code will produce `script.sh b a "c d".txt`. It could be not exactly the desired outcome.

If your file with parameters contain fields separated by something unusual, then you can modify a special variable `IFS` before `read` - then the `read` will split the line by the value of `IFS`.

If you need something even more elaborate, you can use `xargs`, `awk`, or even go to a full scale languages like `perl` or `python`. There are tons of solutions.

Comment: no, if you do `./script.sh $REPLY` and the input line is `a b "c d"`, you pass the four arguments `a`, `b`, `"c`, and `d"`. Try e.g. `echo 'a b "c d"' | while read; do printf "<%s>\n" $REPLY; done`. It's the same issue as with any variable, see [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373) It would work ok for filenames that don't contain whitespace or glob characters, though (or backslashes, if you don't use `read -r`)

Comment: @ilkkachu Your mistake is with `printf` It does its own splitting of the arguments. Since you passed just one `%s` into format, it reads the remainder of the line and splitting it by space. The `printf` does not pay attention to quotes like `read` does. Try the same code with a real script which counts arguments.

Comment: a real script that counts arguments? Like this: `n() { echo "$#"; }; echo 'a b "c d"' | while read; do n $REPLY; done`? It prints `4`, for those four args I mentioned.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the way you described is not how it works. `printf` doesn't see the command line as given, no program started by the shell does. The shell itself does the expansions and runs word splitting (etc.) on the results, giving an array of strings that then get passed to the command. And `$REPLY` gets word-split based on the same rules as any variable.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking about the way `read` itself works? Something like `read x y <<< "a b c d"` would leave `a` in `$x`, and `b c d` in `$y`. Or just `read x y <<< "a b c d"` would leave the whole of `a b c d` in `$x`, effectively not doing splitting. But that's different from word splitting on the command line.

Comment: if you want a separate command to test with, create `script.sh` with `printf "1: <%s> 2: <%s> 3: <%s>\n" "$1" "$2" "$3"`, and then `echo 'a b "c d"' | while read; do  bash script.sh $REPLY; done`. (or the same with a hashbang and `+x`) The output is `1: <a> 2: <b> 3: <"c>`, which should do to show that the `"c d"` part gets split on the space and the quotes aren't special there.